# Using ng-repeat on a string that contain a json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jersey, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have this situation: i want to use ng-repeat directive on a String that contains Json line. This string come from a rest service with jersey. When i call the page that contains this directive there is an error. How i can resolve this situation? Thanks to all.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:1035:14)
at defaults.defaults.transformResponse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6933:18)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6908:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:302:11)
at transformData (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6907:3)
at transformResponse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:7589:17)
at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:10943:81)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11029:26
}
```

This is my code:

**list.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
   <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ person.lastname }}</td>
   <td>{{ person.tasks }}</td>
   <td>{{ person.skills }}</td>
   <td><a ng-click="editUser(person.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Modifica</a></td>
   <td><a ng-click="deleteUser(person.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Elimina</a></td>
</tr>
```

**services.js**

```
services.factory('PersoneFactory', function ($resource) {

return $resource(baseUrl + '/GestRisorse/rest/person/personList', {}, {

    query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false  }, 
   })
});
```

**controller.js**

```
app.controller('PersonListCtrl', ['$scope', 'PersoneFactory', 'PersonFactory', '$location',
  function ($scope, PersoneFactory, PersonFactory, $location) {

 $scope.persons = PersoneFactory.query();

  }]);
```

**restController.java**

```
@Path("/person")
 public class PersonRestController {

   private PersonDAO personDao = new PersonDAO();

     @GET
     @Path("/personList")
     @Produces("application/json")
     public String getPersonList() {

        return personDao.getAllPerson();
            }
    ...
    }
```

**personDao.java**

```
public String getAllPerson(){
        DBCollection collection = connection.getCollection("users");


        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
        try {
           while(cursor.hasNext()) {
               s.append(cursor.next());
           }
        } finally {
           cursor.close();
        }


        return s.toString();

    }
...
}
```

Comment: I think, the problem is getting JSON string instead of real JSON response. Could you please parse as JSON...means, change controller line as $scope.persons = JSON.parse(PersoneFactory.query()); and check

Comment: @Asik thanks, now i have this error :

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/GestRisorse/js/controllers.js:52:27)
    at invoke (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3704:17)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3715:23)
    at $get (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6766
    at boundTranscludeFn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5649:21) <div class="container ng-scope" ng-view="">

Comment: Could you please check the response console.log(PersoneFactory.query())

Comment: Seems the way you're building the String from the Mongo cursor is incorrect. Each iteration appends a new JSON object. So you are left with `{ .. } { .. }`, which is not valid JSON.

Comment: @Asik this is the log: Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}

Comment: Ok..please try my answer!

Comment: @Asik I add this on the controller :
 PersoneFactory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);
     }, function(errResponse) {
       console.log("errore");
     });

Comment: I believe, it works?

Comment: @Asik i add this in the controller:
 PersoneFactory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        // success
        //$scope.persons = data; 
        //In case response is as a string 
        $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data);
     }, function(errResponse) {
       console.log("errore");
     });
but at the end theris this error

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.parse (native)
    at fromJson (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:1035:14)
    at defaults.defaults.transformResponse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6933:18)
   
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEach 
    at transformData (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6907:3)
  
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11029:26

Comment: please log the "data" console.log(data) before parsing...

Comment: @Asik console.log(data) -> Resource {0: """, 1: "{", 2: " ", 3: "\", 4: """, 5: "_", 6: "i", 7: "d", 8: "\", 9: """, 10: " ", 11: ":", 12: " ", 13: "{", 14: " ", 15: "\", 16: """, 17: "$", 18: "o", 19: "i", 20: "d", 21: "\", 22: """, 23: " ", 24: ":", 25: " ", 26: "\", 27: """, 28: "5", 29: "4", 30: "6", 31: "6", 32: "8", 33: "1", 34: "c", 35: "5", 36: "8", 37: "d", 38: "e", 39: "d", 40: "a", 41: "6", 42: "f", 43: "f", 44: "7", 45: "8", 46: "3", 47: "3", 48: "7", 49: "c", 50: "1", 51: "c", 52: "\", 53: """, 54: "}".....}

Comment: @Asik now the error is : 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/GestRisorse/js/controllers.js:57:31
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:10943:81)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11029:26
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:11949:28)
 at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest 
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply 
at done 
    at completeRequest 
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (

Comment: humm, it may be your response from your JAVA? can you confirm this..

Comment: @Asik probably the problem is the String that i pass to parser in the controller, but like you can see from the log : "Resource {_id: Object, name: "asd", lastname: "asd", tasks: "asd", skills: "asda"…}$promise: Object$resolved: true_id:lastname: "asd"name: "asd"skills: "asda"tasks: "asd"__proto__: Resource....... "
it was ok , or not? what kind of json i must pass to parser?

Comment: @peeskillet so i must insert another 2 {} at the beginning and at the end of the string s ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the people that wrote comment under my question, i want to say them that I found the problems, there where 2:

1) i didnt use properly the promise, now i add in the controller these line

```
PersoneFactory.query().$promise.then(function(data) { $scope.persons = JSON.parse(data); },  function(errResponse) { console.log("errore"); });
```

2) i didnt format json properly, so the string that came from backend wasn't a valid json.

Thanks to all.